Entity Framework Core: query arbitary data gives "Sequence contains no elements"
I use latest Entity Framework Core on .NET 8:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.8" />

I want to get results from an arbitrary query (in addition to the normal typed flow, I want to have ability to run an arbitrary SQL query too), I simplified my code to the below console application:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

var c = new TestContext();
c.Database.EnsureCreated(); // passed

var result = c.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(
        FormattableStringFactory.Create(
            "SELECT * FROM History" // history table exists, but I also tried just SELECT 1 as 'Value' with same result
            ))
    .DefaultIfEmpty() // fails with and without this step
    .ToList();

// the above code fails with `Sequence contains no elements` error

Console.ReadKey();

class TestContext: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(sensitiveDataLoggingEnabled: true);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

Not sure what's failed exactly and for what reason.
UPDATE:
It looks like the problem is related to generic type, the below code works:
var result = c.Database.SqlQuery<Dto>(
        FormattableStringFactory.Create(
            "SELECT 1 as 'Value'") 
            )
    .ToList();

where Dto is a class with single int Value property. Is there a way to use dynamic (or similar) option here? I want to provide an arbitrary query and do not specify particular type for mapping (at least on the db level)

dynamic won't work - EF needs a concrete type in order to map query columns to object properties. In general, you cannot achieve what you want with EF Core - it is not designed for "arbitrary queries" with unknown column/property name/types.

@IvanStoev, yeah, I've just noticed this too (see my update), it is not designed for "arbitrary queries" with unknown column/property name/types. - it's sad :( but thanks

Yes, unfortunately. But since you have raw SQL, then plain ADO.NET would achieve relatively easily what you need - obtain a DbConnection, create DbCommand, ExecuteReader and here you go - you have fields and a way to iterate over the resultset row by row, read these fields and put them into arbitrary object. Idk, may be there even exist other helper lib for such things, like Dapper :-/ Nothing prevents you from combining EF Core with other libraries - at the end, all they use ADO.NET for performing the actual db access.
